# Problems with setting up docker server

Tags: azerothcore

When trying to set up AC on docker when running docker compose up -d I get an error midway. Here it is:

```
docker compose up -d
[+] Running 11/11
✔ ac-database 10 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                     150.4s
   ✔ 9a5c778f631f Pull complete                                                                                  113.2s
   ✔ 9e77c3a95bf2 Pull complete                                                                                    1.6s
   ✔ 8b279a2086e0 Pull complete                                                                                    4.1s
   ✔ c8bfbcde7882 Pull complete                                                                                    9.1s
   ✔ d35b074b68ec Pull complete                                                                                    6.4s
   ✔ beea5014e6af Pull complete                                                                                    9.2s
   ✔ dc3791a61558 Pull complete                                                                                  124.5s
   ✔ 52f9323b9f0e Pull complete                                                                                   10.9s
   ✔ 7f7391eab49b Pull complete                                                                                  102.0s
   ✔ 8d2f04b287ee Pull complete
[+] Running 1/9
 - Network azerothcore-wotlk_ac-network       Created                                                            104.2s
 - Network azerothcore-wotlk_default          Created                                                            103.0s
 - Volume "azerothcore-wotlk_ac-client-data"  Created                                                            102.7s
 - Volume "azerothcore-wotlk_ac-database"     Created                                                            102.3s
 ✔ Container ac-client-data-init              Started                                                            102.0s
 - Container ac-database                      Starting                                                           102.1s
 - Container ac-db-import                     Created                                                             56.3s
 - Container ac-authserver                    Created                                                             52.6s
 - Container ac-worldserver                   Created                                                             52.5s
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:3306 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

When I ran it the second time it pretty much did the same thing.... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show `docker compose` file?